# Typescript for Error handling in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

What will be the type of `error` in action.ts that is handled by handled in catch block of worker saga ?

**action.ts**

```
const actionError = (error): IFluxStandardAction => {
  return {
    type: ACTIONTYPE_ERROR,
    payload: error
  };
};
```

**saga.ts**

```
function* WorkerSaga(value) {
  try {
    const { payload } = value;
    const response: Response = yield call(clientApi, payload);
    yield put(Actions.Success(response));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(Actions.Error(error));
  }
}
```

```
Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7044)
```

Comment: It will be `error: Error` in most cases (unless somebody not throws something that is not an `Error`, e.g. `throw 'some string'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by @AlekseyL. in the comments, it it usually but not always an [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object.  **A `catch` clause requires that you catch `any` or `unknown`.**  You can check if it's an `Error` with `if (error instanceof Error)`.

---

An `Error` is non-serializable.  Ideally you would extract some properties from it in your saga or action creator rather than passing a non-serializable object in an action.  It's easy to extract a `string`.

```
catch (error: any) {
  yield put(Actions.Error(String(error) || "An unknown error occurred"));
}
```

The `string` conversion of an `Error` object is like this:

```
String(new Error("some message"))
 --> "Error: some message"
```

Here is a type-safe helper for converting an `any` error to an object with `name` and `message`.

```
interface ErrorData {
  name: string;
  message: string;
}

const toError = (error: any): ErrorData => {
  if (error instanceof Error) {
    return {
      name: error.name,
      message: error.message
    };
  } else {
    return {
      name: "Error",
      message: error?.toString() || "An unknown error occurred"
    }
  }
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wgrvyW)